# PHP apply if condition in foreach loop results

Tags: php

I don't have much knowledge in PHP, your help appreciated.

I created a database query and foreach loop in PHP for getting data from database,
Here is my foreach code:

```
if($user->id != 0)
{
    foreach ( $results as $result) {
        $leftday = $result->dayleft;
        $subsexp   = "-";

        if( strpos( $leftday, $subsexp ) !== false ) {
            echo "Subscription Expired<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Subscription Active<br>";
        }
    }

}
```

Here the result as expected:

- Subscription Expired
- Subscription Expired
- Subscription Active
- Subscription Active

But how can I show only one "Subscription Expired" text when there are no any "Subscription Active"? Now it's showing 4 times "Subscription Expired" text when all subscription expired.

Comment: How many records do you have with `Subscription Expired`? And how many records do you have in total?

Comment: It's not fixed, it's based on the product purchased. Note: all products are subscription based.

Comment: How do you display your records? You display only that subscription value from database? Your question seems a bit unclear, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ionut Just show message "Subscription Expired" if no active subscription found. $results var created for $results = $db->loadObjectList(); if you need. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can create a `SQL` query to count all the rows with `Subscription Expired` in it. And if returned result is bigger than `0` make a condition to show the `Subscription Active`, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is

"When all subscriptions are expired show the message only once" then use an array to store the results (active / expired). Once you have all results stored you can process the array (if all expired do this, else do that).
If you echo the resutls right away as you do now, without storing the results, you cannot act upon them, something like:

```
<?php

$results = [];
$results['active'] = 0;
$results['expired'] = 0;
if($user->id != 0)
{
    foreach ( $results as $result) {
        $leftday = $result->dayleft;
        $subsexp   = "-";

        if( strpos( $leftday, $subsexp ) !== false ) {
            $results['expired']++;
        } else {
            $results['active']++;
        }
    }

}    //all expired
if(0 == $results['active']){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: It's showing an error: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object... (for line $leftday = $result->dayleft;)"

Comment: I used $results var for a database query "$results = $db->loadObjectList();"

Comment: Thanks, your idea works, I just changed the var name in the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can set two flag variable one for   Expired and another for Active
in for each loop increase  no of active and Expired (active =active+1)
(Expired =Expired+1) . you will git all active and Expired .at the just compare total result from database to total Expired if both are equal you can show only one  Subscription Expired

```
  $TotalData=count($results);
    $active=0;
    $Expired=0;
      foreach($results as $val)
       {
       if()
       {
        $active=$active+1;
       }
       else
       {
        $Expired =$Expired+1;
       }
       }

   if($Expired==$TotalData)
   {
   echo "Subscription Expired";

   }
```